# Java class represents a number

Tags: java, numbers

I have an instance of a class:

```
Class<?> myClass = ...;
```

Now I want to find out whether this class represents a number, i.e all primitives and their wrappers + BigDecimal + BigInteger.

For all wrappers and Big* classes I use

```
Number.class.isAssignableFrom(myClass)
```

Is there a way to find out that more generally also for primitives? One way that comes to my mind is to test additionally like this:

```
Number.class.isAssignableFrom(myClass) || (myClass.isPrimitive() && myClass!=char.class && myClass!=boolean.class)
```

PS: it seems that the primitives (not even their classes) are really part of the java class system. Could you provide more information/reference on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is OK. It seems that it covers the issue.

Comment: I am thinking about the guarantees that Java gives, that in the future releases no new primitive types will be added.